# A British idiom describing ordinary people?

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english, idiom-requests

Could anyone help me find a phrase/idiom which is used to describe an ordinary person? I remember it's something like 'a man on ___ bus'. I read it several weeks ago in the Economist or the Guardian, but I can't remember exactly.

Comment: Whilst not an answer to the specific phrase requested, a more generic idiom describing "ordinary people" could be "the man on the street".

Comment: Muggles ... (from 1997 on)

Comment: "...hobbits.." (mumbled under your breath of course). Source: https://78.media.tumblr.com/92376e5f3a0342590f31c79e03dd3c4a/tumblr_mze4blCOkd1rrohoto1_250.gif

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are thinking of [the man on the Clapham omnibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus). In British law he is a hypothetical, reasonably educated, ordinary person you use to compare expected conduct or behaviours with when dealing with things like negligence.

Source: Too much time in the law library while my wife was in law school, and [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_man_on_the_Clapham_omnibus)

Comment: I love the common law names for types of people. The fertile octogenarian and the precocious toddler are two very interesting concepts in common law.

Comment: Please note that this idiom is totally unknown outside the UK (and is not commonly known even there as far as I know). You may have to think about whether your audience will recognize it.

Comment: I wouldn’t say totally unknown outside the UK (I’m in Canada) but certainly restricted to legal circles I think!

Comment: It's mostly restricted to legal circles even in the UK: the more common equivalent is "the man in the street", who is probably not necessarily as well educated as the omnibus passenger.

Comment: Does not political correctness now require it to be "the person on the Clapham omnibus"?

Comment: @SGR: U.S. tort law has, I believe, "the eggshell-skull plaintiff."

Comment: @Sven Yargs: that's not limited to the US. The 'eggshell-skull' is a phemonenon in UK legal circles too.

Comment: @WS2 almost certainly not, in the Law (and general conversation) man can be assumed to be a generic person - from the Wikipedia page, “The man on the Clapham omnibus is a reasonably educated, intelligent but nondescript person”.

Comment: As a reasonably well-read Brit I was familiar with the expression but didn't know of its legal origins.

Comment: This is the term, although it is a bit limited in its use. Personally I'd use it in articles similar to the economist or guardian in tone, and change it to "Man on the Street" or "Joe Bloggs" as an alternative when speaking less formally.

Comment: I'm from Australia, and while I'm familiar with this expression, I don't think I've ever heard it used by non-Brits. (FWIW, I now have [Up the Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_the_Junction_%28song%29) running through my head. ;) )

Answer (score 7):

If you need it more colloquial:

- Joe Bloggs (UK)
- John or Jane Doe (US)
- the general public
- grassroots
- rank-and-file

If you want to be a bit condescending (hey, sometimes we all do):

- The proletariat
- Hoi polloi
- common people
- Plebs

Comment: "Plebs" could go in the second list as well

Comment: @Yann As could "Joe Six-Pack" since the 2008 U.S. Presidential election primaries...